# Dead alcoholic gets a second chance, helped by Judas

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

This story is about a recently deceased man, who finds himself walking along a dark plain towards soothing glowing in the distance. He is accompanied by a hooded figure. There are doors. He is made to believe that he can change his fate if he can identify, relive, and correct the one critical moment in his life. This works, and he is saved. The dark figure takes hope from a rare success, and returns to his critical moment. He is receiving pieces of silver, and is revealed to be Judas.

I would have read this in the late 60's, but I was reading a lot of older stuff at the time, so it could be from the 50's. It was part of a collection of short stories, either a magazine or anthology.

Comment: What other input can you give to this question?   When did you read it ~?  Was it a short story? from a magazine or small novel?

Answer (score 8):

Robert F. Young, [“A Drink of Darkness”](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?93412), in [*The Worlds of Robert F. Young*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?50563).

> In this story an alcoholic named Chris meets a gaunt man who takes him to a back alley bar and buys him a drink. The drink renders Chris unconscious. When he comes to, he and the gaunt man are walking down a corridor lit by stars, heading toward a shining mountain. On either side of the corridor are doors where Chris revisits moments from his past. When they reach the mountain, the man tells him he has the opportunity to relive a pivotal moment of his life, and if he does it differently and correctly, his life will be extended. Chris chooses the key moment and he succeeds in changing his past.
> Then the gaunt man resolves once again to try his hand at changing his own crucial moment. He finds himself in a temple with the high priest who hands him a leather bag containing 30 pieces of silver. He agrees to point out the One they’re looking for by giving Him a kiss. <sub><sup>[Review - Robert F. Young / Eclectic Pilgrim Blog](https://eclecticpilgrim.wordpress.com/tag/robert-f-young/)</sup></sub>

Comment: It would help if you explain how this fits the description.

Comment: Is that description in your own words? If not, it would be good to acknowledge your source.

Comment: @user14111 - It seems to have been lifted from the author's own blog. I've added a link